# Stack Overflow reputation API

Tags: support

I am creating one wordpress widget plugin that display different types of social media fans and followers counts. After that I feel that i also include Stack Overflow reputation for specific users. How can i get the Stack Overflow reputation for any user? is there any api for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. The method you're looking for is `/users/{ID}`. Example:

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/1

Which returns JSON data looking like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "reputation": 17246,
      ...
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that if you are using JavaScript to access the API, you will need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: This answer is currently obsolete due to the API 1.1 shutdown and the addition of new routes.

Answer (score 3):

Since now 1.1 is deprecated the following url is to be used to get the reputation score:

```
/2.2/users/{id}?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow
```

See [the docs for `/users/{ids}/reputation`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users).